# AWS ECS instance missing `ecs.capability.efsAuth` attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a custom ECS AMI, running Debian 10. I launch the ECS-Agent as a container, as suggested in the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-install.html#ecs-agent-install-nonamazonlinux). Everything works fine.

Recently, I was asked to integrate EFS into the cluster, so that containers running within specific tasks would have access to shared, persistent storage.

I added the efs-utils package to the AMI build, as documented in the [git repo](https://github.com/aws/efs-utils). The instances *themselves* now automatically mount to EFS on boot, and users on the instances can read/write to the EFS mount.

However, tasks configured to use the `efsVolumeConfiguration` parameter in the task volume definition fail to get placed; the good old `Container instance missing required attribute` error.

Because the instances themselves have no problem mounting to EFS on boot, I've implemented a workaround using regular docker volumes, so the containers running in the task mount EFS on the host via normal docker volume, but I'd prefer to have the ECS -> EFS integration working properly.

When I run the ECS-CLI `check-attributes` command against any of the instances in my cluster I get:

```
ecs-cli check-attributes --task-def my-task --container-instances my-container-instance-id --cluster my-ecs-cluser
Container Instance                    Missing Attributes
my-container-instance-id  ecs.capability.efsAuth
```

And indeed, in the console, when I go `cluster`->`instances`->`specific-instance`->`actions`->`view/edit attributes`, all of the `ecs.capability.xxx` contain empty values.

When do these values get populated? How should I augment the AMI build so that these values get populated with the proper values?

Please let me know if you need any additional information.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this functionality of using EFS with ECS is supported on Debian based systems since the documentation [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/efs-volumes.html#efs-volume-considerations) does not provide commands for Debian.

Still, try these steps:

1. Install efs utils and enable amazon-ecs-volume-plugin [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/efs-volumes.html#efs-volume-considerations)
2. Add the tag manually: [2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement-constraints.html#add-attribute)

   - Name=ecs.capability.efsAuth
   - Value=`<empty>`

Comment: Thanks for the response :-)

So i do mention that efs-utils get built and installed in the source AMI that I spin cluster instances from. The amazon-ecs-volume-plugin gets enabled during the build out of efs-utils.

In terms of manually adding instance attributes, unfortunately, attributes that start with `ecs` are reserved, so you can't manually add the missing ecs.capability attributes (i tried this way also) 

I appreciate the help -- i really just need to figure out where and when those instance attributes get populated so I can continue to dig :-)

Comment: @Taliesin did you ever figure this out? I'm stuck on the same issue. I have the attribute ecs.capability.efs but not ecs.capability.efsAuth

Comment: I think I solved this. From https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/blob/3776bee911c2267dedce46a9d2a17007f0bd73ae/agent/config/config_test.go#L143 I saw where to set efsAuth, so placing it in my config file at /etc/ecs/ecs.config: ECS_VOLUME_PLUGIN_CAPABILITIES=["efsAuth"] worked

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I thought I marked this as the answer a long time ago.

Answer from @bravinator932421

> I think I solved this. From github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/blob/… I
> saw where to set efsAuth, so placing it in my config file at
> /etc/ecs/ecs.config: ECS_VOLUME_PLUGIN_CAPABILITIES=["efsAuth"] worked

This also worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I got it when trying out Bottlerocket, which apparently does not support encrypted EFS mounts. Removing the transit encryption requirement fixed it.